# How to store randomly generated unsigned int numbers in a bitset

Tags: c++

I have a bitset in which I need to store a # of randomly generated integers (store its bit representation of course). So, the thing is that I am confuse on how to do that.

i.e suppose that I generate the integers (all unsigned int) 8, 15 , 20, one at a time. How can I store the recently generated integer in my existing bit set.

Say that I start by generating "8" and store in the bitset, then I generate "15" and store it in the bitset.

I don't know or don't understand how to store those values within the bitset.

Note: I know in advance the size of the bitset, the size is based on the number of integers that I am going to generate, and that I know too. So, at the end what I need is a bitset with all the bits set matching the bits of all the generated integers.

I'll Appreciate  your help.

Comment: Is there any reason you would want to use a `bitset` instead of a `set` or an `unordered_set`?

Comment: I think it will be easier to store the numbers as integers and create the corresponding `bitset` when you need it.

Comment: Hi @gha.st , I want to use a bitset since it would allow me to access the bits easily. Some times I would need to access the **nth** bit. Or read from bit **a** to bit **b**. Etc, and I have read that bitset is quite good to do that.

Comment: @RSahu how do you suggest I can do that ? At the end what I need is a bitset<N> where **N** has to be the size of all generated integers. I know in advance how many random integer I am  going to generate, so I create the bitset with that size. Is that helpful to understand what I need to do ? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I store the recently generated integer in my existing bit set.

You can generate a temporary `bitset` form the integer and then assign values between the two `bitset`s.

Example program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
   const int size = sizeof(int)*8;
   std::bitset<2*size> res;
   std::bitset<size> res1(rand());
   std::bitset<size> res2(rand());

   for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i )
   {
      res[i] = res1[i];
      res[size+i] = res2[i];
   }

   std::cout << "res1: " << res1 << std::endl;
   std::cout << "res2: " << res2 << std::endl;
   std::cout << "res: " << res << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
res1: 01101011100010110100010101100111
res2: 00110010011110110010001111000110
res: 0011001001111011001000111100011001101011100010110100010101100111
```

**Update**

A function to set the `bitset` values given an integer can be used to avoid the cost of creating temporary `bitset`s.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <climits>

const int size = sizeof(int)*8;

void setBitsetValue(std::bitset<2*size>& res,
                    int num,
                    size_t bitsetIndex,
                    size_t numIndex)
{
   if ( numIndex < size )
   {
      res[bitsetIndex] = (num >> numIndex) & 0x1;
      setBitsetValue(res, num, bitsetIndex+1, numIndex+1);
   }
}

int main()
{
   std::bitset<2*size> res;
   int num1 = rand()%INT_MAX;
   int num2 = rand()%INT_MAX;
   std::bitset<size> res1(num1);
   std::bitset<size> res2(num2);

   std::cout << "res1: " << res1 << std::endl;
   std::cout << "res2: " << res2 << std::endl;

   setBitsetValue(res, num1, 0, 0);
   setBitsetValue(res, num2, size, 0);

   std::cout << "res:  " << res << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is actually helpful although I'm concerned about the performance because I'm gonna be generating a lot of integers and that means that if I for example generate 1000000 integers I would have 1000000 temporary bitsets. Is there a way to just have one bitset and just set the bits of each newly generated integer?

Comment: @CarlosDavid, I suspect there are tricks to avoid the temporary `bitset`. I don't know it off-hand.